# How to make a JavaFX Group not move around when just adding children?

Tags: javafx-2

If you watch the following test, you'll see that all the circles move around instead of just a new one being added. It doesn't happen every time. I think it's only when the new child is outside the existing bounds. But how do I get it so that it will not move the group and all it's children when I add another circle, regardless of where I put the circle?

Note, that if I don't set the scale on the Group, they won't all move. So it's related to setting the scale.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

import java.util.*;


public class GroupTest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        Group root = new Group();
        // NOTE: removing these two setScale* lines stops the undesirable behavior
        root.setScaleX(.2); 
        root.setScaleY(.2);
        root.setTranslateX(100);
        root.setTranslateY(100);

        root.layoutXProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number number2) {
                System.out.println("root layout: " + root.getLayoutX() + ", " + root.getLayoutY());
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Node>() {
            @Override public void onChanged(Change<? extends Node> change) {
                System.out.println("root: " + root.getBoundsInParent());
                System.out.println("root: " + root.getBoundsInLocal());
                System.out.println("root: " + root.getLayoutBounds());
                System.out.println("root: " + root.getLayoutX() + ", " + root.getLayoutY());
            }
        });

        pane.getChildren().add(root);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        new Thread(() -> {
            Random r = new Random();
            try {
                while (true) {
                    expand = expand * 1.1;
                    Thread.sleep(700);
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        root.getChildren().add(new Circle(r.nextInt((int)(1000*expand)) - 500*expand, r.nextInt((int)(1000*expand)) - 500*expand, r.nextInt(50)+30));
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    static double expand = 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First, I want to say that the behavior you see can be achieved through a much smaller program, let alone those calculations you do for the circles. `r.nextInt(250)` for the positions of the circles would have been enough to see the behavior and is much easier to see what happens. Also, for debugging, I added a visible rectangle to the pane that is bound to the Group's layoutbounds, where you can see what happens:

```
final Rectangle background = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

    root.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
      @Override
      public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable, Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) {
        background.setX(newValue.getMinX());
        background.setY(newValue.getMinY());
        background.setWidth(newValue.getWidth());
        background.setHeight(newValue.getHeight());
      }
    });
    background.setFill(null);
    background.setStroke(Color.RED);
    pane.getChildren().add(background);
```

**So, what happens here?**

From the [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Group.html)'s API:

> Any transform, effect, or state applied to a Group will be applied to all children of that group. Such transforms and effects will NOT be included in this Group's layout bounds, however if transforms and effects are set directly on children of this Group, those will be included in this Group's layout bounds.

Looking at the result with your scale turned on:

[image]

You see that the bounds of the group are larger than whats inside. This is because of how the transformation is applied: The children of the group are transformed, but for the calculation of the bounds of the group the scaling is not considered. **Thus, the group is on the pane where the union of the untransformed bounds of the circles are, then transformations for the circles are applied.**

Compare with this statement with the result when the scaling is turned off:

[image]

To sum up, this is by design and not a weird behavior, because the **Group is always as big and positioned accordingly where the union of its untransformed children bounds are.**

**EDIT**

If you want the nodes to be scaled at the position they are and the group not move, I suggest to scale the children of the group directly. This implementation of your thread changes the scaling of the circles every 5 circles, but they stay at the same position:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
      private int count = 0;
      private double scale1 = .5;
      private double scale2 = .2;
      private double currentScale = scale1;
      @Override
      public void run() {
        final Random r = new Random();
        try {
          while (true) {
            expand = expand * 1.1;
            Thread.sleep(700);
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                System.out.println(count);
                Circle c = new Circle(r.nextInt(250), r.nextInt(250), 30);
                c.setScaleX(currentScale);
                c.setScaleY(currentScale);
                root.getChildren().add(c);
                count++;
                if (count > 5){
                  count = 0;
                  if (currentScale == scale1){
                    currentScale = scale2;
                  } else {
                    currentScale = scale1;
                  }
                  Iterator<Node> iterator = root.getChildren().iterator();
                  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Node next = iterator.next();
                    next.setScaleX(currentScale);
                    next.setScaleY(currentScale);
                  }
                }
              }
            });
          }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Great thorough explanation of the why. Now... how to make it seem to not do it. Meaning, how to make existing nodes appear not to move when a new node is added. There ought to be a way of somehow calculating a reverse transformation or something to get it to work.

Comment: I don't exactly understand your requirement, however, i edit my answer to contain an example that uses scaling and the nodes stay at their position.

Comment: I'm building a panning/zooming UI. Transforming each node individually is not workable.

Answer (score 4):

The real problem here is that the Group's pivot point -- the relative point for rotation and scaling -- is dependent on the Group's layout-bounds. Therefore, if layout-bounds change, due to adding new children (or existent children changing position, size, or rotation), the relative point for all transformations on the Group changes as well.

In the JavaFX source code, you can find the definition of the pivot point in the Node.java file. The methods `impl_getPivotX()` and `impl_getPivotY()` return the center x resp. y coordinate of the layout-bounds.

Unfortunately, there is no option to manually set the pivot point. But as every Node manages a list of additional transformations which are applied on top of the standard transformations, you can easily achieve the desired behaviour:

```
final Scale scale = new Scale();
group.getTransforms().add(scale);

// change scale
scale.setX(2);
```

Comment: @taotree, It would be awesome to get some feedback. Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Because you change size of the group after each circle being added, thus triggering relocation of the Group inside the Pane.

You can either:

1. add circles directly to pane

   ```
   pane.getChildren().add(new Circle(...
   ```
2. add a large background to fix Group size:

   ```
   // numbers are huge because you are using 1/5 scaling
   Rectangle base = new Rectangle(-10000, -10000, 20000, 20000);
   base.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
   root.getChildren().add(base);
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but neither solution is acceptable. I always might add a circle to 30000 so have the same problem. And I need to be able to move the Group as a whole, so I can't add the circles to the Pane.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem drawing a signal which has some values that came out of the bounds.

Use a Pane instead of Group. You use absolute positioning also and it does not move arround its bounds.
[Pane JavaFx 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use javafx.scene.layout.Pane instead of javafx.scene.Group.

Comment: This could be for a slightly different problem, but switching to a Pane can sometimes fix these problems. 

This is because the Pane does not automatically infer its size from its children in the same ways as a Group (as already mentioned by the other answers).